# Avoiding -inf when calculating Log Likelihood (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, exponent

When using MATLAB to calculate

Log_likelihood=log((1/1e8)*exp(-0.5*SSR)),

if SSR (i.e. standard squared error) is large (e.g. SSR=1e4) then the exp() becomes zero and the Log_likelihood becomes -inf.

Is there any numerical/mathematical trick that can handle this problem?

Thank You

Comment: A naive approach would be something like `p = (1/1e8)*exp(-0.5*SSR);` followed by `p(p < 1e-100) = 1e-100;` ... `Log_likelihood=log(p);`

Comment: you should combine the log and the exp process. read this http://lingpipe-blog.com/2012/02/16/howprevent-overflow-underflow-logistic-regression/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your `log` is a natural logarithm:

```
log(a*exp(b)) = log(a) + log(exp(b)) = log(a) + b.
```

Where `a=(1/1e8)`, `b = -0.5*SSR`

Moreover, `log(1/1e8) = log(1) - log(1e8)`, so the above turns to be `-log(1e8) + b`, while the first term is a constant and can be precalculated.