# How to circumvent the extremely small output values?

Tags: matlab, precision

For example in Matlab:

```
log(exp(-200)
-200
```

however

```
log(exp(-2000))
-inf
```

Naturally the input to the `log` function is passed as zero as `exp(-2000)` is insignificant and the `log` gives `-inf`. How can I fix this to receive -2000 instead?

Comment: A man goes to the doctor. At the appointment, the patient begins to swing his arm in an unnatural way and says, "it hurts when I do this." The doctor responds, "then don't do that."

If `log(exp(x))` introduces too much error, you shouldn't do that.

Almost certainly your algorithm/formulas can be rewritten, reengineered to not require the computing of `log(exp(-2000))` and not introduce massive numerical error. A general theme in numerical methods / scientific computing is to write formulas and design algorithms in such a way as to be numerically stable.

Comment: Well no argue per say, except for the log(exp(-2000)) is just an example. I'm dealing with a problem in which the range of the values results in similar insignificant results and the inf problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html), it's possible to do this with [Variable Precision Arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html).  Use the `vpa` function and place your mathematical expression as input into `vpa` wrapped in a string:

```
>> vpa('log(exp(-2000))')

ans =

-2000.0
```

However, this will be represented in symbolic format, so it may be prudent to convert back to a numerical value after you're done.  Convert this result using [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) once you perform the calculation:

```
>> double(vpa('log(exp(-2000))'))

ans =

       -2000
```

Comment: Such string arguments for vpa are deprecated, better use `log(exp(sym(-2000)))` or if you explicitly want to use `vpa` use `vpa(log(exp(sym(-2000))))`

Comment: @Daniel I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but the symbolic method is not what I actually am looking for. I'm more interested in knowing if I can ask either Matlab or R to increase the precision on a single function output.

Comment: That's not what your original question says.

Comment: Please do not fall pray to the XY problem. I'm flagging your post with an appropriate duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It is often possible to rewrite formulas in a way they do not exceed the range of floating point values. In your case, rewriting it would be trivially `-2000`. A more "real world" example can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372670/avoiding-inf-when-calculating-log-likelihood-matlab) where rewriting successfully avoided the problem.

Comment: Yes! this is almost certainly what OP should be doing. Another fun/simple/subtle example is that the logistic function should be written as `1 ./ (1 + exp(-x))` instead of `exp(x) ./ ( 1 + exp(x))`. The latter generates NaN when x is large and the formula requires computing inf/inf.